# Написание модуля для drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Есть материал позиция с текстовыми полями и картинкой. Пишу модуль который будет выводить форму загрузки позиций. вот текст модуля formtest.module <code><?php

```
<?php

function formtest_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['formtest/form'] = array(
    'title' => 'My form',
    'page callback' => 'main_function',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => 'My form',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function my_first_form($form, &$form_state){
    $form=array();
    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Название поля'),
        '#default_value' => t('Текст по умолчанию'),
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}

function main_function(){
    $form = drupal_get_form('my_first_form'); //получаем поля формы
    $form = drupal_render($form); //рендерим форму
    return $form.'Содержимое тестовой страницы.';
}

function my_first_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    debug($form_state['values']);
}
?>
```

Теперь по адресу formtest/form доступна эта форма. Теперь нужно сделать чтобы я мог её выводить на любую страницу как блок и при заполнении формы создавалась новая позиция с типом моего материала

Второй вопрос снимается. Новые материалы создаются с помощью класса StdClass

Answer (score 1):

А чтобы выводить форму в блоке дописываем вывод её в блок:

```
 function formtest_block_info() {
  $blocks['formtest_block'] = array(
    'info' => 'Форма добавления ноды',
    'status' => TRUE,
    'visibility' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function formtest_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'formtest_block':
      module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
      $block['subject'] = 'Добавление ноды';
      $block['content'] = main_function();
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Теперь этот блок можно вывести в любое место на странице либо через интерфейс Drupal'a, либо программно:

```
$formtest_block = block_block_view('formtest_block');
print render($formtest_block['content']);
```

Так как в форме присутствует загрузка картинок, то нужно добавить функцию `HOOK_menu_alter`:

```
function formtest_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['file/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['file/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
  $items['system/ajax']['file path'] = drupal_get_path('module', 'node');
  $items['system/ajax']['file'] = 'node.pages.inc';
}
```

Есть уже готовый модуль реализующий такой функционал [Advanced Form Block](https://drupal.org/project/afb)

Если в форме не подразумевается загрузка файлов, можно сделать так: Тип материала уже есть, значит есть и форма его добавления, добавляем в форму нужные поля через CCK, далее создаём модуль в котором добавим блок с этой формой добавления материала по примеру выше, только в функции  `formtest_block_view`  напишем

```
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = node_add('машинное_имя_типа_материала');
$output = drupal_render($form);
$block['subject'] = 'Добавление ноды';
$block['content'] = $output;
```

Или без создания кастомных модулей, на странице в нужном диве вызываем эту форму:

```
 <?php 
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    print drupal_render(node_add('машинное_имя_типа_материала'));
   ?>
```

Но тайтл страницы изменится на "Добавление материала..", это удобно если форму выводим на отдельной странице, а если форму нужно вывести на странице на которой присутствуют другие материалы, то немного изменим код

```
global $user;
$type = 'машинное имя материала';
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => $type, 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
$form = drupal_get_form($type.'_node_form',$node);
print drupal_render($form);
```

Но это не кошерно и лучше загнать код формы в переменную и отрисовать в шаблоне. Для этого используем HOOK_preprocess_page()

```
function THEME_NAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    global $user;
      $type = 'ТИП_МАТЕРИАЛА';
      module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
      $node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => $type, 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
      $form = drupal_get_form($type.'_node_form',$node);
      $variables['my_form'] = drupal_render($form); // Добавляем нашу переменную
    }
```

Теперь в page.tpl.php будет доступна переменная $my_form содержащая код формы.
Есть ещё кучка вариантов как вывести форму добавления ноды. Друпал очень гибкий фреймворк и как реализовать такую задачу зависит только от фантазии разработчика. 
Советую заглянуть на api.drupal.org как правило там есть ответы почти на все возникающие вопросы по разработке на Drupal.